# edit getValue() on javafx property - listener not notified

Tags: java, javafx

I added listener like this,

```
FwDescriptionListView.itemsProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println("Old = " + oldValue + ", new = " + newValue);
});
```

and edited ListProperty value like this,

```
FwDescriptionListView.itemsProperty().getValue().remove(descText);
```

Why listener wasn't notified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView`'s `itemsProperty` is an `ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>` (where `T` is the type of object in the list). A change listener registered with it will be notified if you replace the entire list, i.e. if you do

```
fwDescriptionsListView.setItems(someWholeNewList);
```

Of course, that's not what you are doing: you are merely removing an element from the list. (Note that your code is equivalent to `fwDescriptionListView.getItems().remove(descText);`, which is the more common way of doing this.)

To listen for changes in the list, you register a [`ListChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.html) with the list:

```
fwDescriptionListView.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends T> change) -> {
    System.out.println("List changed");
});
```

where, again you replace `T` with the type of the elements of the list. You can get more information about what actually happened to the list (items added, items removed, etc) from the `change` parameter: see the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) for details.